# set checkbox codeigniter not populating fields

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox

I have a list of sectors that I have retrieved from a database and I am trying to populate only the selected sectors depending on the user. There are 7 sectors (shown below).

HTML:

```
<p class="sector"><span>North East</span><input type="checkbox" class="sector-list" name="sector[]" value="1" /></p>
<p class="sector"><span>City of Sunderland</span><input type="checkbox" class="sector-list" name="sector[]" value="2" /></p>
<p class="sector"><span>Sunderland East</span><input type="checkbox" class="sector-list" name="sector[]" value="3" /></p>
<p class="sector"><span>Sunderland North</span><input type="checkbox" class="sector-list" name="sector[]" value="4" /></p>
<p class="sector"><span>Sunderland West</span><input type="checkbox" class="sector-list" name="sector[]" value="5" /></p>
<p class="sector"><span>Coalfield</span><input type="checkbox" class="sector-list" name="sector[]" value="6" /></p>
<p class="sector"><span>Washington</span><input type="checkbox" class="sector-list" name="sector[]" value="7" /></p>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
foreach($data['all_sectors'] as $sectors):
    echo"<p class='service'><span>$sectors->sector</span><input type='checkbox' class='sector-list' name='sector[]' value='$sectors->ID' /></p>";
endforeach;
```

Now when the user goes to edit their profile I am trying to pre populate the checkboxes that the user has selected previously.

I am confused as to how I can repopulate the sectors when they created an account. I have tried the following.

CONTROLLER:

```
$data['assigned_sectors'] = $this->info_model->getAssignedSectors();

foreach($data['assigned_sectors'] as $sector) 
    {
        $id_str = array(
            'ID' => $sector->sector_ID
        );
    }
    print_r($id_str);
```

Below is the result for '$data['assigned_sectors']'

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [agency_ID] => 2 [sector_ID] => 3 [ID] => 3 [sector] => Sunderland East ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [agency_ID] => 2 [sector_ID] => 4 [ID] => 4 [sector] => Sunderland North ) )
```

I have tried adding both to the foreach checkbox html but no luck

```
set_checkbox('sector[]', $data['assigned_sectors']->sector_ID) //not working
set_checkbox('sector[]', $id_str->ID) //not working
```

I am probably overlooking something simple but any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE:

```
$this->load->model('admin/info_model');
    $data['agency_sectors'] = $this->info_model->getAgencySectors($agency);

    $this->load->model('admin/agencies_model');
    $data['all_sectors'] = $this->agencies_model->getAgencySectors($agency);

    echo"<p id='sectors'><label for='sectors'>Sector</label></p>";
    echo"<div id='sector_list' style='float: left;width: 70%;'>";
    foreach($data['agency_sectors'] as $sector):
        foreach($data['all_sectors'] as $sectors):
        $selected_text = ($sector->sector_ID === $sectors->ID) 
           ? " checked='checked'" 
             : '' ;
    echo"<p class='service'><span>$sectors->sector</span><input type='checkbox' class='sector-list' name='sector[]' value='$sectors->ID' " . $selected_text . "/></p>";
        endforeach;
    endforeach;
    echo"</div>";
```

If there are 2 agency sectors selected out of the 7 it duplicates the list twice, same for 3 results and so forth

Comment: are you using that inside the input tag?

Comment: The set_checkbox? Yeah I am

Comment: Can you post that line and state what the expected and actuals are?

Comment: <p class='sector'><span>$sectors->sector</span><input type='checkbox' class='sector-list' name='sector[]' value='$sectors->ID' " . set_checkbox('sector', '1') . " /></p> even if I add a hard-coded value of 1 the checkbox doesn't check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `name` attribute should match the first parameter to `set_checkbox`:

change:

```
set_checkbox('sector', '1')
```

to:

```
set_checkbox('sector[]', '1')
```

******UPDATE****

My previous answer was incorrect. You cannot set the checkbox selected state with `set_checkbox` from a value in the database. [See @Raidenace's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16423891/844726).

You'll have to set it by checking if the value is the same within a loop:

Instead of this code:

```
<p class='sector'><span>$sectors->sector</span>
  <input type='checkbox' class='sector-list' name='sector[]' 
    value='1' " 
      . set_checkbox('sector', $data['assigned_sectors']->sector_ID) . " />
</p>
```

Try this code:

```
$selected_text = ($data['assigned_sectors']->sector_ID === $sectors->ID) 
                   ? " checked='checked'" 
                     : '' ;
<p class='sector'><span>$sectors->sector</span>
  <input type='checkbox' class='sector-list' name='sector[]' 
    value='$sectors->ID' " . $selected_text . " />
</p>
```

Comment: Even with the name changed it still doesn't even check one checkbox, regardless of the value

Comment: Right, I just tested it too. I just read @Raidenace's answer and after looking at the docs (`Permits you to display a checkbox in the state it was submitted.`) - it seems that is the correct answer. `set_checkbox` is not designed to decide to select a checkbox based on a value, but by the `$_POST` value of that particular checkbox item.

Comment: I am pulling the results from a database, how would I get the correct checkboxes selected?

Comment: just check to see if the values match, then set the `checked` state on the checkbox - I've updated my answer with that solution.

Comment: That worked great apart from one problem, if there are more than one checkboxes assigned, it duplicates the whole list of sectors and checks the correct ones. I am using a foreach for all of the sectors, then a foreach for all assigned sectors. I have updated my question with my controller code

Comment: @Pooshonk: I think the order of these two statements should be swapped:    `foreach($data['agency_sectors'] as $sector):
        foreach($data['all_sectors'] as $sectors):` Loop, all_sectors first and agency_sectors second

Comment: I didn't realize that you needed to loop both. I'm not a big fan of "loops within loops" - so I would probably create an array of **agency sector ids** (maybe with [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)), then check if the `$sectors->ID` is in the new array with [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: I solved it, I was doing something wrong outside of the loop which totally screwed it up. Had to array_push to get it to work. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Great. Well if you feel my answer helped to solve your problem, could you mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this seems unintuitive but the set_checkbox() function "lets you set the selected value of a checkbox **via the value in the POST array** that is passed. So this is meant to revert a checkbox to the value that the user had selected during a form submission, in the use case of the form getting validated and the user is returned back to the same form due to, say, validation errors. I do not think that is what you are trying to get done in your case.

I had to figure it out from their function definition

```
/**
 * Set Checkbox
 *
 * Let's you set the selected value of a checkbox via the value in the POST array.
 * If Form Validation is active it retrieves the info from the validation class
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string
 * @param   string
 * @param   bool
 * @return  string
 */
if ( ! function_exists('set_checkbox'))
{
    function set_checkbox($field = '', $value = '', $default = FALSE)
    {
        $OBJ =& _get_validation_object();

        if ($OBJ === FALSE)
        {
            if ( ! isset($_POST[$field]))
            {
                if (count($_POST) === 0 AND $default == TRUE)
                {
                    return ' checked="checked"';
                }
                return '';
            }

            $field = $_POST[$field];

            if (is_array($field))
            {
                if ( ! in_array($value, $field))
                {
                    return '';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (($field == '' OR $value == '') OR ($field != $value))
                {
                    return '';
                }
            }

            return ' checked="checked"';
        }

        return $OBJ->set_checkbox($field, $value, $default);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for exploring the code which helped me extend it with this small FYI::

Manipulating the $_POST variable by setting it will result in CI checking that particular option. i.e $_POST['checkbox_name'] = $value;